# Is there a way to override the schema names for dbt Cloud CI runs?

Tags: continuous-integration, dbt

We use dbt cloud to run our dbt project. On CI runs, dbt Cloud uses a schema name related to the PR number, e.g. `dbt_cloud_pr_5205_543`.

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Update: we've updated our macro as below.

```
generate_schema_name.sql 
% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}      
    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}      
    {%- if target.name[-3:] == 'dev' -%}          
        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}      
    {%- elif target.schema[:9] == 'dbt_cloud' -%}          
        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}      
    {%- elif custom_schema_name is none -%}          
        {{ default_schema }}      
    {%- else -%}          
        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}      
    {%- endif -%}  
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastián, can you expand more on what you mean by "sinter" type of schema? Are you referring to the `target` schema of the dbt project?

Comment: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/dbt-cloud/using-dbt-cloud/cloud-enabling-continuous-integration-with-github/

we are no longer seeing the dbt schemas generated in the ci jobs

Comment: we updated our macro as follows as per dbvt
`generate_schema_name.sql`
`% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}

    {%- if target.name[-3:] == 'dev' -%}

        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- elif target.schema[:9] == 'dbt_cloud' -%}

        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- elif custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}`

Comment: I'd recommend moving this macro to an answer and closing this as a self-answer Q&A post. Looks like a useful macro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro resolved the problem:

```
generate_schema_name.sql 
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}

    {%- if target.name[-3:] == 'dev' -%}

        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- elif target.schema[:9] == 'dbt_cloud' -%}

        {{ target.schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- elif custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```